# React Native: How do you implement DatePickerAndroid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

According to the RN docs, you have to call an async/await function to open the Android Date Picker.  I've tried installing the Async to generator transform Babel preset and adding a .babelrc file with

`{
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}`

but that just seems to throw an unexpected token error when adding any RN component using tags (eg < Image ... /> would throw and unexpected token error).  This is what my function to open the Android Date Picker looks like

```
async openAndroidDatePicker: function() {
  try {
    const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
      date: new Date()
    });
  } catch ({code, message}) {
    console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. my function's syntax was wrong... this is what worked for me:

```
async openAndroidDatePicker() {
  try {
    const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
      date: new Date()
    });
  } catch ({code, message}) {
    console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind I was using createClass for this examples, not es6 classes.

Answer (score 12):

My way without any packages, only using docs [DatePickerAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid) and [TimePickerAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timepickerandroid.html)

import components what you need. For me are:

```
import {
Text,
SafeAreaView,
TouchableOpacity,
View,
Platform,
StatusBar,
DatePickerIOS,
Slider,
DatePickerAndroid,
TimePickerAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MainStyles from '../styles/MainStyles';
```

Then set your state:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
 this.state = {
   chosenDate: new Date(),
   chosenAndroidTime: '00:00',
   androidDate: `${new Date().getUTCDate()}/${new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1}/${new Date().getUTCFullYear()}`,
   value: 50,
 };
}
```

After declarate funcs:

```
setDate(newDate) {
  this.setState({ chosenDate: newDate });
}

setDateAndroid = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      action, year, month, day,
    } = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
    date: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    });
    if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
      this.setState({ androidDate: `${day}/${month + 1}/${year}` });
    }
  } catch ({ code, message }) {
    console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
  }
};

setTimeAndroid = async () => {
  try {
    const { action, hour, minute } = await TimePickerAndroid.open({
      hour: 14,
      minute: 0,
      is24Hour: false, // Will display '2 PM'
    });
    if (action !== TimePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
      // Selected hour (0-23), minute (0-59)
      const m = (minute < 10) ? `0${minute}` : minute;
      const h = (hour < 10) ? `0${hour}` : hour;
      console.log(`time: ${hour}:${minute}`);
      this.setState({ chosenAndroidTime: `${h}:${m}` });
    }
  } catch ({ code, message }) {
    console.warn('Cannot open time picker', message);
  }
};
```

Finally add to your view container:

```
       {
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
            <DatePickerIOS
              date={chosenDate}
              onDateChange={this.setDate}
            />
          ) : (
            <View style={MainStyles.AndroidDatePickerWrap}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setDateAndroid()}>
                <View style={MainStyles.HistoryTime}>
                  <Icon name="ios-calendar" size={25} color="rgb(49, 49, 49)" />
                  <Text style={[MainStyles.HistoryTimeText, { fontSize: 16 }]}>
                    {androidDate}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setTimeAndroid()}>
                <View style={MainStyles.HistoryTime}>
                  <Icon name="ios-time" size={25} color="rgb(49, 49, 49)" />
                  <Text style={[MainStyles.HistoryTimeText, { fontSize: 16 }]}>
                    {chosenAndroidTime}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )
        }
```

As a result you must see differt picker for iOS and android.
This is works for me, hope this will help for you.

Comment: This is a great solution. Make sure to change {androidDate} to {this.state.androidDate}. And similar for {chosenAndroidTime}.

Comment: @Serj It's the finest and simplest solution you can get for DatePicker and TimePicker. Thank you for sharing the solution, it really works well :)

Answer (score 4):

I used a library for the Date picker android in my app.
Check the sample for usage:

```
'use-strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import{
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,

}from 'react-native';

import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
var {width,height} = Dimensions.get('window');

class Booking extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {

  date_in: '2016-05-01',
  date_out: '2016-05-01',

 };
}

 render(){

return(
  <View>

  <Text style={{fontSize:18, marginLeft:10, marginTop:10}}>Arrival/Departure:</Text>

  <DatePicker
      style ={{padding:10}}
      date={this.state.date_in}
      mode="date"
      format="YYYY-MM-DD"
      minDate="2016-05-01"
      maxDate="2016-06-01"
      showIcon={false}
      customStyles={{
       dateInput: {
          alignItems : 'flex-start',
          padding:5
      },
     }}
    onDateChange={(date_in) => {this.setState({date_in: date_in});}}/>

  </View>
);
}
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({

  picker: {
   width: 100,
  },
 });

 module.exports = Booking;
```

For more details you can look here :

[Date picker react native](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Have you been able to use RN Core's DatePickerAndroid API?

Comment: I have not used RN Cores DatePickerAndroid yet.. as library implementation was quite easy...

Answer (score 1):

Just call this function on one of your DatePicker button

```
openDatePicker() {
    try {
      DatePickerAndroid.open({
        date: new Date()
      }).then(date => {
        if (date.action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
          //Please take note that the number of the months is based on 
          //the count of an index, let say January is 0, February is 1 and so on...
          //if you want the count to be  1 to 12 for months, then add 1

          const finalDate = `${date.month + 1} ${date.day} ${date.year}`;
          console.log(finalDate)

          //Let say i pick February 10 2019, the output will be 2 10 2019
          //You can use moment to format the date as you like 

          //Here's an example:
          //console.log(moment(finalDate, 'MM DD YYYY').format('LL'))
          //Output: February 10, 2019
        }
      });
    } catch ({ code, message }) {
      console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
    }
  }
```